# Running shell or Bash scripts with zsh on macOS v11 (Big Sur)

Tags: command-line, permission, script, zsh

Every time I need to run a shell script, I need to enter

```
chmod +x <filename>
```

For example, if I want to run this sample script named "run",

```
#!/bin/bash

javac --version
```

I have to go into my terminal

```
chmod +x run
./run
```

Is there a way to allow [Z shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) (`zsh`) always to run these scripts without having to enter `chmod +x <filename>`?

Comment: Note that `zsh` does _not_ run the script unless you explicitly tell it to with `zsh ./run`. If you just do `./run`, the shell mentioned in the shebang (here, `#!/bin.bash`) is the shell that will run the script.

Answer (score 18):

You only need to run `chmod` once for a script, not each time you run it. If you don‘t want to do this, you can also use `bash ./run` to execute it.

You can also create a text file with the executable bit set once, and then use it as a template in your editor of choice to create new scripts based on it.